# Get iOS ID not FCM Id in Ionic 2 with Phonegap Push Plugin

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification, ionic2

I'm developing app in Ionic 2. I installed phonegap push plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push to get notifications and get device ID.

When I'm in Android App the device ID of return is a GCM ID, but when I'm in iOS he return FCM Id, and I don't need that, I want get Push Plugin register:

This is example of my issue:

`FCM Registration Token: cqs2H3ED5u8:APA91bEVQGi0SfbC1Yau1xN_PJB0SOmB50PgHMNG2zCqw4bzWfLruXfqKoIT7DeJnz5K37CqQLIs9F-CXfwurC-UhZjfLNUvnEfCZDpIleW_6xGZYZKokNcIPouGHdvdSnVMhHu6mITh`

```
Push Plugin register success: <5c27c9a8 87e28030 735f8bc7 e27ab8de e6d6538f c9759e70 26c306a6 fa0ac2cc>
```

How to configure push plugin init to make this change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I open issue on Phonegap project. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1982

The answer was 
 “Yes, when you remove the GoogleService-Info.plist from iOS it uses APNS but as long as you keep delivering google-service.json it uses FCM. Actually, Android won't work without the google-service.json file”

If you want use APNS on iOS platform you have to remove GoogleService-info.plist (is optional on iOS and necessary on Android)